# Error in my removeAllChildren function

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite

I thought i should be smart and made/copy a removeAllChildren function which worked nice. But now I get "Error #2069: The Loader class does not implement this method" If i understanded it correctly so is it because I have a loaded picture in a Sprite. *(But I'm almost sure it worked with the same type of pictures when I build the function as now.)* I cant figure out how to go around it. Think catch error should work somehow, but havn't succeded with it. Or is something else I doing wrong?

This is the picture in R class

```
public static var picture:Class;
    [Embed(source="picture.png")]
```

The child:

```
private var bg:Sprite=new R.picture;
canvas.addchild(bg);
```

My removechildrenfunction:

```
public static function removeAllChildren(doc:*):void {
while(doc.numChildren){
  if (doc.getChildAt(0) is DisplayObjectContainer)
        removeAllChildren(doc.getChildAt(0));
            doc.removeChildAt(0);


                }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are sending removeAllChildren function parameter typed as [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)

from Loader Reference

> The Loader class overrides the following methods that it inherits,
>   because a Loader object can only have one child display object—the
>   display object that it loads. Calling the following methods throws an
>   exception: addChild(), addChildAt(), removeChild(), removeChildAt(),
>   and setChildIndex(). To remove a loaded display object, you must
>   remove the Loader object from its parent DisplayObjectContainer child
>   array.

```
public static function removeAllChildren(doc:*):void {
    if(doc is Loader && doc.parent != null)
    {
        doc.parent.removeChild(doc);
        return;
    }
    while(doc.numChildren){
        if (doc.getChildAt(0) is DisplayObjectContainer){
            removeAllChildren(doc.getChildAt(0));
        }
        doc.removeChildAt(0);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that I cant automate it, I have to write in my class removeChild(canvas), if we take my example?

Comment: it says if it is a Loader object dont remove any children just remove Loader object from it's parent i added code to answer

Comment: This solutions don't work, because of this is a function of a function and when if loader removes doc.parent.removechild(doc) it will be a problem in the parentfunction it will try to remove that the childfunction already removed. But its only to put in row if (doc.numChildren==0) return, after removeAllChildren(doc,getChildAt(0)); (Have never thought of that you can make a return in a void function before, which I guess will make some function lot easier)